# Eclipse: strange syntax errors

Tags: android, eclipse, syntax

Eclipse is driving me crazy today and comes up with nonsense errors like this one here:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token ";", delete this 
 token
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
 Statement
```

This is my code:

```
View dialogView = (View) findViewById(R.layout.dialog);
    imgMan = new NovelImageManager();
    this.viewMan = new ViewManager(dialogView, this.imgMan);<--- Error happens here.
```

I have weird problems in other Projects like this one:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    loadData();

    if (adView != null) {
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    } else {
        setupAds();
    }
}
```

causes the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token "void", @ 
 expected
- overrides 
 android.app.Activity.onResume
```

The codes worked in the past, so I have no idea why eclipse is acting like that.
I know eclipse can be a pain sometimes, but this doesn't make sense.

Any Idea what this could cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean and Build is your friend here! Especially if you're recently added new resources etc.

Comment: This is always the first thing I do if eclipse starts misbehaving :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Please update to ADT 20.0.1. The bug has been fixed.

---

This is a [bug in Android Lint](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33985). It "holds" Java related errors from the JDT, if you hit the save button at a time where a Java syntax error is present.

You can hit the "Remove all warnings" button in the Android Lint view to get rid of those wrong warnings. Lint will re-create the correct warnings during the next run.